# Error when evaluating expression on v-if

Tags: vue.js

I need way to check if value in Vue component. Here is my code:

```js
var userContent = Vue.extend({
      template: `

      <div class="LayersMenuSectionContent" v-if="userContent.rasters_previews_list.data.length > 0">
           <!-- Display only if  userContent.rasters_previews_list.data.length > 0 -->

           <ul v-for="img in rasters_previews_list">
             {{img.id}}
             <input type="checkbox" /> Layer 5 <br>
           <ul>           
       </div>

          `,
        data: function ()  {
          return {
            rasters_previews_list: [{id:'aa'},{id:'aa'}]
          }

          },

          ready: function()
          { 

          }

});
```

But I am getting error: 
`Error when evaluating expression "userContent.rasters_previews_list.data.length > 0". Turn on debug mode to see stack trace.`

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `userContent`? You don't have that in your data.

Instead, check `rasters_previews_list` directly:

```
v-if="rasters_previews_list.length"
```